# Pandas trim leading & trailing white space in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

develop a function that Trims leading & trailing white space.

here is a simple sample, but real file contains far more complex rows and columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["A b ",2,3],[np.nan,2,3],\
[" random",43,4],[" any txt is possible "," 2 1",22],\
["",23,99],[" help ",23,np.nan]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

the result should eliminate all leading & trailing white space, but retain the space inbetween the text.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["A b",2,3],[np.nan,2,3],\
["random",43,4],["any txt is possible","2 1",22],\
["",23,99],["help",23,np.nan]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Mind that the function needs to cover all possible situations.
thank you

Comment: Can you show us both an input and and output of what you're after, as well as what you've tried so far. Try to detail what is going wrong.

Comment: @scagood, the second code should give a final result of what it should look like

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think need check if values are strings, because mixed values in column - numeric with strings and for each string call `strip`:

```
df = df.map(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
print (df)
                     A    B     C
0                  A b    2   3.0
1                  NaN    2   3.0
2               random   43   4.0
3  any txt is possible  2 1  22.0
4                        23  99.0
5                 help   23   NaN
```

If columns have same dtypes, not get `NaN`s like in your sample for numeric values in column `B`:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
print (df)
                     A    B     C
0                  A b  NaN   3.0
1                  NaN  NaN   3.0
2               random  NaN   4.0
3  any txt is possible  2 1  22.0
4                       NaN  99.0
5                 help  NaN   NaN
```

(original answer used applymap which is [depreciated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap))

Answer (score 25):

I think there is a one-liner for that using regex and replace:

```
df = df.replace(r"^ +| +$", r"", regex=True)
```

Explanation for the regex:

- ^ is line start
- (space and plus, +) is one or more spaces
- | is or
- $ is line end.

So it searches for leading (line start and spaces) and trailing (spaces and line end) spaces and replaces them with an empty string.

Comment: Just FYI: "Regular expressions will only substitute on strings" says [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).