# Get rid of initial spaces at specific cells in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I am working with a big dataset (more than 2 million rows x 10 columns) that has a column with string values that were filled oddly. Some rows start and end with many space characters, while others don't.

What I have looks like this:

```
   col1                    
0 (spaces)string(spaces)    
1 (spaces)string(spaces)  
2 string    
3 string   
4 (spaces)string(spaces)
```

I want to get rid of those spaces at the beginning and at the end and get something like this:

```
   col1                    
0 string   
1 string 
2 string    
3 string   
4 string
```

Normally, for a small dataset I would use a for iteration (I know it's far from optimal) but now it's not an option given the time it would take.

How can I use the power of pandas to avoid a `for` loop here?

Thanks!

edit: I can't get rid of all the whitespaces since the strings contain spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas trim leading & trailing white space in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551336/pandas-trim-leading-trailing-white-space-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

might help

Comment: `df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(str.strip)`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `strip`.

Comment: y the apply? y not directly use str.strip?